# Nginx proxy_pass when service not available

Tags: nginx, redirect

Is there a way to make nginx redirect to a plain html page when the underlying express application is not responding?

I'm looking for a way to alert the users if the app is not working rather then getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

I have seen there are some npm packages that can do this but they require a manual setting in the config file.

I would need this to be done automatically.

Comment: Why not just specify a custom error page for the 500 error(s) you're expecting?

Comment: geez.. your right.. got too much into things that I forgot the basics... Let me see..!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
location /example {
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  proxy_pass http://example.com;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 =500 /proxy_server_error.html
  error_page 404 /proxy_not_found_error.html
}
```